# Use translator service to translate text inside public static array

Tags: php, symfony, translation

I am displaying a user's current status on a user profile page. 
There are 3 possible statuses and are saved in the database as integer (1 = account enabled, 2 = account disabled, etc ...)

To format the integer to meaningful text, I have created a Twig extension in which I list all 3 possible statuses in a public static array as followed:

```
public static $aAllowedStatuses = array(
    StatusModel::STATUS_DISABLED => 'Account disabled',
    StatusModel::STATUS_ENABLED => 'Account enabled',
    StatusModel::STATUS_TECHNICAL_PROBLEM => 'Account disabled because of technical problem'
);
```

I would like to translate these texts, so I injected the translator service into my twig extension and tried changing

```
StatusModel::STATUS_DISABLED => 'Account disabled'
```

to

```
StatusModel::STATUS_DISABLED => $this->translator->trans('Account disabled')
```

But I'm getting this error in my IDE (phpStorm): Expression is not allowed as field default value

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot evaluate any code while defining properties in PHP.

What you can do is to translate them in a constructor for example:

```php
public function __construct(Translator $translator)
{
    foreach (self::$allowedStatuses as $key => $message) {
        self::$allowedStatuses[$key] = $translator->trans($message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's a nice solution. But when I'd like to extract translations (via jms/translationbundle) it displays this error: Can only extract the translation id from a scalar string, but got "PHPParser_Node_Expr_Variable"

Comment: That wasn't your question... If you need to extract translations, you'll need to adapt to extractor's limitations.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an expression in the array-construction.

You could do it afterwards, like this:

```
$aAllowedStatuses[StatusModel::STATUS_DISABLED] => $this->translator->trans('Account disabled');
```

Comment: Although I checked the other answer as "answer for my question", I used your line of code in order to use the extract command :)